# Avoid Blank Screen while transitioning Activity Screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have Two Activities A and B

A is starting B like

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(A.this, B.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.down_slide_out);
        finish();
```

where

R.anim.right_slide_in  is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
       android:fromXDelta="+100%p"
       android:toXDelta="0"
       android:duration="700"
     />
</set>
```

and 
R.anim.down_slide_out is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   <translate
      android:fromYDelta="0"
      android:toYDelta="+100%p"
      android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

This work great. B comes sliding from right and A goes out sliding down.

Problem is during this transition. A Blank Screen appears as background of whole app[image: See Here]

How to avoid that ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try to reduce duration `android:duration=""`

Comment: @SPK read comment carefully what you should reduce

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you. And, sorry for misunderstood the question. I didn't saw that duration in that xml file

Comment: not worth it reducing duration. had tried it all .

Comment: "How to avoid that ?" -- what are you expecting to be there?

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the comment . yes i missed mentioning this in my question. can i set any thing over there. a background of my own. ?

Comment: to atleast make it look matching with the application theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Possible As far As Application Layer is Concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an application theme (e.g., `<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme">`) that sets the `android:windowBackground` attribute to a drawable, such as:

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: It didn't work out. It do set the background of each activity on one place . but didn't fill the area that i questioned

Comment: @Javanator: No, sorry, not off the top of my head.

Comment: seems like no solution for this.. anyways thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
move_to_left.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

move_to_right.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

</set>

startActivity(recipeCategoriesIntent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_to_left, R.anim.move_to_right);
```